# The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing (newbie)

Tags: node.js, gitlab, continuous-integration, cypress, pipeline

I see many instances of this question but nothing that helps me. Apologies if this question gets boring.

I am just starting out with node.js, Cypress and GitLab Pipelines.

I've cobbled together something that has a simple web app, a few simple tests.
It ran fine the first time but, on subsequent commits, it fails at the 'Cypress Tests' step with: `The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.`

There's a lot more to the log but I don't know what is relevant.

Here is my yml file

```
cypress tests:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89
  cache:
    key: package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules
  before_script:
    - npm install
    - npm run dev &
    - ./node_modules/.bin/wait-on http://localhost:3000
  script:
    - npm run cypress
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
```

Could you please help with anything that looks like it might be the culprit?
Or at least help me understand how to read the situation better?
I tried reading the docs as much as I can, I just can't see the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner but I'm trying to answer. First you can add `"cypress:open" : "cypress open"`  to the file package.json. For more details you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjoBbs3u1-8&ab_channel=NATASATech)